# Python print objects design

Tags: python, python-2.7

On the following classes, each object has it's own (customized) print function called **pprint**.

*(There is more objects in the actual code than what's presented below).*

```
class Device(object):
    """
    Device: a MAC address, a name (optional), an ip(s) (optional),
    and a list of Interface objects.
    """
    def __init__(self, ip='', name='', mac=''):

    def addIp(self, ip):

    def getInterface(self, name):

    def removeDuplicates(self):

    def pprint(self, disp=MORE):

    def toCSV(self, outputFolder=outputPath):


class Interface(object):
    """
    Interface: a name, a status and a set of Link objects.
    It can be physical (port) or virtual (interface).
    e.g: name  : BAGG1,
         status: TRUNK,
         links : [(vlan1, mac1), (vlan2, mac2), ...]
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.links = []
        self.status = ''

    def addLink(self, vlan='', destMAC=''):

    def getValues(self):

    def _removeDuplicates(self):

    def pprint(self, disp=MORE):
```

**Among the following options, what is better/more efficient/more Pythonic ?**

- **1. Put a pprint function inside each class (like above):**

  - **Advantage:** `obj.pprint(args)` is easy to use.
  - **Disadvantage:** *every* object I want to print has its own pprint function, so it decreases code readability for what really matters in the class.
- **2. Have a dedicated Printer class:**

  ```
  class NetworkPrinter(object):        
      def __init__(self, obj):  

      def pprint(self, disp=MORE, keyList=None, filters=[], padding=20):

      def devicePrint(self, disp=MORE):

      def interfacePrint(self, disp=MORE):
  ```

  ***Note:*** pprint will call the appropriate print function based on the type of the object.

  - **Advantage:** Code is more organized.
  - **Disadvantage:** Have to import the class, create a printer object and call it each time to get the pprint function: 
    `import Printer`
    `p = Printer()`
    `p.pprint(obj)`
- **3. Have no dedicated Printer class:**

  ```
  def pprint(obj, disp=MORE, keyList=None, filters=[], padding=20):

  def devicePrint(obj, disp=MORE):

  def interfacePrint(obj, disp=MORE):
  ```

  ***Note:*** pprint will call the appropriate print function based on the type of the object.

  - **Advantage:** Don't have to instantiate any Printer object. Can call directly `pprint(obj)` for any object.
  - **Disadvantage:** Code less organized and kind of messy.

Comment: I typically implement a `__repr__` or a `__str__` method. Then I can use standard "print" or "logging" functions. Seems more Pythonic to me. I guess this is most like your option 1. Option 2 and 3 mean that the Printer class has to have detailed knowledge of the implementation of the other classes, which seems like a violation of basic object oriented principles. But this is more of an opinion question which is typically frowned upon at SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to add `__str__` method to each class definition and then print using standard builtin: `print(class_instance)`. Internally, python calls `__str__` to get a string representation of the instance.

Comment: Ok but my print functions have additional arguments like disp, filters, padding, ..., which allow me to customize the output.
Is there a way to pass more arguments to print ?